# How to import React component locally from a different create-react-app project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I've created 2 React applications called `client` and `admin-client`, both using `create-react-app`.

In `admin-client`, I'd like to reuse some components that already exist in `client` in order to avoid code duplication.

For example, I have a `Header.jsx` file inside `client/src/components/` directory which I want to reuse in `admin-client`, which looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

function Header() {
    return (
        <header>
            <h2>Hello World!!</h2>
        </header>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

#### Here's what I've tried (and failed):

I've created an `.env` file inside `admin-client` project directory as follows:

```
NODE_PATH='./../'
```

(`admin` and `admin-client` are in the same parent directory)

Then inside `admin-client/src/App.jsx`, I try to import `Header.jsx` as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Header} from 'client/src/components/Header.jsx';

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

But I get the following error:

```
../client/src/components/Header.jsx 5:8
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| function Header() {
|     return (
>         <header>
|             <h2>Hello World!!</h2>
```

I prefer to find a solution that doesn't involve dealing with Babel and/or Webpack directly, because it's the reason that I'm using `create-react-app` in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a simple task if you do it manually, You'll probably end up on making a lot of changes on your repo just to make it in sync to your other apps. I suggest that you install a package called `Bit` which lets you share and sync UI components between your projects. You can read more about it here: https://docs.bit.dev/docs/installation.html

> NPM
>
> Install Bit using NPM:
>
> npm install bit-bin --global
>
> When installing Bit on windows, add the --no-optional flag: npm install bit-bin --global --no-optional

Comment: thank you, I can now reuse my React components. Do you have any suggestions on reusing SASS styles as well? Currently I have a separate .scss file for each React component. But I can only export the components, not the styles.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your shareable react project as a **dependency** for your other project, you can mention it in your package json dependencies, and import the things like how we do in any other node projects.

Mentioning a medium post here which I came across: 
https://medium.com/@Powderham/sharing-react-components-between-separate-projects-self-hosting-with-git-installing-with-yarn-npm-d3275b64239c

Let me know if this helps.